# What wiki would you recommend to base a new wiki solution upon?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, open-source, wiki, wiki-engine

Using C#, preferably Asp.net MVC I want to implement a wiki solution which consists of a unique markup language and article display. However I also want to provide standard wiki features such as RSS, Versioning, ext.

What existing wiki would you recommend me to base upon?

Comment: You should reconsider using unique markup. It makes it hard for users. Use the Wikipedia standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a mature ASP MVC wiki, but in the asp.net webforms area [screwturn](http://www.screwturn.eu/) is my favourite.

Answer (score 1):

[screwturn.eu](http://screwturn.eu) is your friend. It go all the other tricky stuff solved (and there is a lot of that!)

You can easily replace the page formatter pipeline (core/FormattingPipeline.cs in screwturn) or more simply just add custom formatters

MVC is nice but shouldn't be a requirement for a wiki which is effectively just one page (default.aspx in screwturn's case)?

You should be able to use Url re-writing to make each page have a pretty URL, this is how MVC framework work any ways

e.g. site.com/pageName > site.com/pageName.ashx